# Alternatives to Azure elastic pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, cloud, multi-tenant, azure-elasticpool

I'm designing multi-tenant SaaS solution. I've read [Multi-tenant SaaS database tenancy patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns)
 article and [Multi-tenant app with database-per-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns#d-multi-tenant-app-with-database-per-tenant) seems to be the best option for me. It looks very attractive because it offers database management tools for all existing databases. It's possible to update database schema for all tenants at once. But is it the only existing option? I didn't find any AWS or Google cloud alternatives to Elastic pools. Are there any?

Maybe there is a better solution to get separate database for every tenant? For example using docker/kubernates.

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can find information related to multi-tenancy on two main options for the solution you are working on:

1. There’s an option into Cloud Datastore for configuring partitions of your data by regional scopes, you can find more in [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy)
2. You can also create a GKE environment to support cluster-multi-tenancy. Give a look to the available [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multitenancy-overview)